# elegant way to filter list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have  two list like following way.I need to extract value from after = i.e. xyz and .81.
I am trying to make one general solution for both list or make for future also.
As of now, I was doing join and find int the list than split. But I feel it can be done in better way.

```
a = ['.TITLE', "'=", 'xyz', 'vdd', '=', '0.81', 'temp', "-40'"]
b = ['.TITLE', "'$", 'abc', '=', 'xyz', 'vdd', '=', '0.99', 'temp', "125'"]
```

Comment: What about `'0.99'`, should that be included?

Answer (score 6):

You could use [`next()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next) with a generator:

```
a = ['.TITLE', "'=", 'xyz', 'vdd', '=', '0.81', 'temp', "-40'"]
a1 = iter(a)
for item in a1:
    if '=' in item:
        print next(a1)
```

Prints:

```
xyz
0.81
```

Note that if `=` is the last item, this will raise a `StopIteration` error.

---

You could also use [`enumerate()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
a = ['.TITLE', "'=", 'xyz', 'vdd', '=', '0.81', 'temp', "-40'"]
for i, j in enumerate(a):
    if '=' in j:
        print a[i+1]
```

Prints:

```
xyz
0.81
```

Once again this will raise an error (`IndexError`) if `=` is the last item.

Answer (score 4):

As a function:

```
import itertools

def extract_items_after(lst, marker='='):
    for x, y in itertools.izip_longest(lst, lst[1:]):
        if marker in x:
            yield y
```

Using your data:

```
a = ['.TITLE', "'=", 'xyz', 'vdd', '=', '0.81', 'temp', "-40'"]
b = ['.TITLE', "'$", 'abc', '=', 'xyz', 'vdd', '=', '0.99', 'temp', "125'"]

for l in [a, b]:
    print list(extract_items_after(l))
```

Results:

```
>>> 
['xyz', '0.81']
['xyz', '0.99']
```

Comment: Beautiful and doesn't raise any exception.

Answer (score 0):

A non elegant way would be to use flags :

```
a = ['.TITLE', "=", 'xyz', 'vdd', '=', '0.81', 'temp', "-40'"]
b = ['.TITLE', "'$", 'abc', '=', 'xyz', 'vdd', '=', '0.99', 'temp', "125'"]

def extract(L,sep="="):
    pick_this_one = False
    for item in L :
        if pick_this_one:
            pick_this_one = False
            yield item
        if item == sep :
            pick_this_one = True

for value in extract(a+b):
    print value

>>> xyz
0.81
xyz
0.99
>>>
```